# Add value (Row) if not exists already in the gridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox

I want to add some rows in datagridview (without binding) from a combobox text property.
but I need first to check if it is already added, it yes then show a message, if not already added, then add the text value of the combo in the gridview.
I am using VS 2010 with C#
I search a lot of all available solutions but not working with me.

I tried to loop on the rows but I couldn't do it,, please help!!

this is my code to add the value but how to check?

```
dgv_standards.Rows.Add(cbo_standard.SelectedValue.ToString(), cbo_standard.Text);
```

Comment: why can't you loop on the rows? how are you accessing the per row cell values? what error do you see?

Comment: thanks for replying, your idea is clear but if the row exist then simple message and break, BUT if ( is not exist) then add row . imagine if the existing row in the third position, then the loop will check the first row(which is already not equal), so it will add new row, but the reality the existing row in the third position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that your `DataGridView` has two columns (?). So if you would like to check whether some row contains the first column string, you can do like this:

*UPDATED according to OP comment:*

```
boolean found = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_standards)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value == cbo_standard.SelectedValue.ToString())
    {
        // row exists
        found = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Row already exists");
        break;
    }
}

if (!found)
{
    dgv_standards.Rows.Add(cbo_standard.SelectedValue.ToString(), cbo_standard.Text);
}
```

Similar for second row, with `row.Cells[1]`.

Comment: thanks for replying, your idea is clear but if the row exist then simple message and break, BUT if ( is not exist) then add row . imagine if the existing row in the third position, then the loop will check the first row(which is already not equal), so it will add new row, but the reality the existing row in the third position

Comment: @user3213767 Hold a `boolean` that is initialized to `false`. First run all over your rows, if one of them is what you are looking for, set it to `true` and break. Next code will be to test the boolean value, if it's false, you can add the row, otherwise, continue.

Comment: Thanks alot. Best !!!  ..really thanks... can you mark the questios as answered and vote, because i cant do it for my low reputation number

Comment: @user3213767 No I can't mark my own question as the accepted answer and neither to up vote it .. I think you should be able to mark as answer (did you try clicking on the 'V'?).